# How to force Android 8 to connect WiFi without internet?

Tags: wi-fi

For some reason, I need to connect my Samsung phone (Android 8.1) to WiFi locally, no internet required.

However as soon as I send some data through it, the connection suddenly get terminated that I have to reconnect again, even when "no internet" prompt have been clicked "keep connection".

No luck in implementing answers from similar topics as well
[Stay connected to specific Wifi which has no internet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130265/stay-connected-to-specific-wifi-which-has-no-internet?rq=1)
neither forgetting entire other network.

Any suggestion? Or it's simply impossible for non-rooted device?

Comment: Does this also happen if you are in flight mode (no mobile connection) and no other configured Wifi is around?

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Doesn't seem to have any effect, remains disconnected after a while